# Is there anyway to place the placeholder text above the input field instead of placing it in the inside

Tags: html, css

So I'm basically making a form but I was requested to place the placeholder text above the text like this [form that I need to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOvsV.png)

But I can't figure out how to do that. I tried placing the text as a label over the input field but when I change the size of the browser the alignment is all over the place so I want to the label to align with the input field above it.

Here is what I tried doing:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <!-- Name of Company -->

  <label class="comp" for="company" style="left: 40px;">Company</label>
  <input type="text" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Company" />

  <!-- Clients First Name -->
  <label class="comp" for="firstname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstN" placeholder="First Name" />
</div>
```

But what I get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKouV.png).

Is there anyone that can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Move the `<input />` inside of the `<label />` and `display: block;` it. If you want to separately style the text, wrap it in a `<span />`.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 10px;
}

input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <!-- Name of Company -->

  <label class="comp">
    Company
    <input type="text" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Company" />
  </label>

  <!-- Clients First Name -->
  <label class="comp" for="firstname">
    First Name
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstN" placeholder="First Name" />
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried adding your snipper but I got something like this 
https://codepen.io/siddiqmo10/pen/eYzbPdO

Answer (score 0):

**Placeholder vs. Label.** 
You can not move the input placeholder text outside of the designated input. Placeholder text is strictly handled by the browser. You may only modify the content using the `placeholder=""` HTML property and style it with CSS pseudo class `::placeholder`.

Instead use the label HTML element like so: 
 (reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

```
<div class="preference">
    <label for="cheese">Do you like cheese?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cheese" id="cheese">
</div>
```

**Display Label Above Input.** 
Now, you mentioned your label is appearing to the left of the input instead above it? You will need to style your CSS like this. **Add the following CSS markup:**

```
label {
    display: block;
}
```

I would also recommend, but not required, setting the display element on your input fields to block as well.

```
input {
    display: block;
}
```

**Why?** 
By default label is rendered as `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` by your browser user-agent. Setting it to `display: block;` will ensure it will always appear above and not inline with the input.